# In graph theory, is there a term for the value of the difference between indegree and outdegree?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

I'm working on a Graph Theory research project, and one of the key components is talking about the indegrees and the outdegrees of a few particular vertices. I need to define a term for the value of indegree-outdegree for a particular vertex. Or for vertex $v$ does the value $\deg^{-}(v) - \deg^{+}(v)$ have a name?

Some possible terms have been "netdegree" or "flow value," which would suffice for my needs, but I would like to make sure I use the existing terminology if possible.

Comment: I don't know of any standard terminology.  I like "net income."

Comment: I believe the word "excess" can also be used (especially if your graph relates to flow networks).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is called the **imbalance** of a vertex, see for example this paper: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42932978.pdf

Note that this is defined as *indegree* - *outdegree*, but clearly this can be easily reversed.